# Ubuntu 18.04 `$DISPLAY` is set to `127.0.0.53` instead of `:0`

Tags: xorg, display, xserver, resolv.conf

I have a freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo T470

I ran into some weird issues, which seemed to be related to rendering of GUI windows on my machine:

- Some code not running correctly and showing the error: `cannot open display 127.0.0.53`
- `code .` not opening via shell, but opening correctly via the GUI (clicking on the VSCode icon)
- Seeing some odd errors like `Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:`

After googling around I figured out that my `$DISPLAY` variable is set to `127.0.0.53`, whilst a co-worker of mine has his variable set to `:0`. 
He did not run into the issues I've ran into, so I decided to manually set the `$DISPLAY` var to `:0`, which fixed the issue.

Every shell I open, the `$DISPLAY` var is set back to `127.0.0.53` for that shell. Also my `resolv.conf` file looks like:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

I would really love some insight as to what is setting this variable to be `127.0.0.53` rather than `:0`, and also how to permanently setting it that way. I read on an ubuntu forum that it is not advised to set the var in `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`?

To be clear, this is all local work, I'm not ssh-ing into a remote server, which seems odd as most of the Q&A I saw on this topic talked about SSH and X Server

P.S `HardInfo` shows the laptop display as having vendor `The X.Org Foundation` which I thought was peculiar and might be related

Thanks a lot

Comment: AFAIK the `resolv.conf` entry is normal (it indicates that your system is using the `systemd-resolved` stub resolver, which is the default for 18.04) and so is the `hardinfo` output. You might want to consider removing the `ssh` tag if, as you say, SSH is not involved in any way (in case the tag is discouraging people from offering an answer).

Comment: I had the same issue as described here. For me it turns out that I forgot to remove some Windows WSL workaround from my .bashrc messing with the display variable, doh...